# Serious latency over SSH: CentOS 6.3 VNC is fine, no visible I/O bottlenecks

Tags: linux, ssh, slow-connection

This is not an issue about logging in via SSH, this is a lag during typing input and receiving output while connected to a server via SSH. I tested the speed of the commands using the time command and see that they are running normally but that input to and output from the terminal is lagging.  VNC is fast.  Pinging remote servers from this server shows normal response times.  SSH sessions to other machines from my machine seem fine.  openssh-server 5.3p1-84.1.el6

The fact that VNC is fast should be enough, but for info, RAM is fine, no swapping is occurring, CPU usage is low, ethtool shows network at 1 Gigabit.

Comment: I should mention that this is a virtual machine running on KVM, so when I connect to VNC, I actually connect to the host at port 5905.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should at your lost packets rate via a ping command. Ssh doesn't like it at all

Comment: There are no dropped packets or errors showing up in ifconfig.

Comment: I was not talking about that but lost ones when you ping your server

Comment: You were right, pings are getting dropped when I ping this server.  How do I resolve?

Comment: You should delete question...

Comment: I can't delete it because it has answers.

Comment: I dont want to accept my own answer, but the issue was dupe MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

I am a knucklehead!  I had duplicate MAC addresses on another VM.  Changing the MAC to be unique instantly resolved the issue.

Comment: Good to know. Next time should use arping